# Get image to overlay on top of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table of basketball stats and I have an image of a basketball court that will later contain a shot chart.  It is initially hidden.  I want the image to only appear when the user clicks a button.  And the image should appear on top of the of table.  (Most of the table will be behind the image)
I can't seem to manipulate the CSS or Jquery position to allow that to happen.  Part of the problem is that I want the table itself to be centered (margin: 0px auto;)

I started a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/f7g9dtxt/ to work it out.  If you click "Show Court" you will see what happens now.  The image is at the bottom and to the left.  Instead of the top and middle.

Code Below:

```
<button id='showimg'>
Show Court
</button>
<table class='mytable'>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>FGA</th><th>FGM</th><th>Rebounds</th><th>Fouls</th>    </tr>
<tr><td>Michael Jordan</td><td>5</td><td>10</td><td>12</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>LeBron James</td><td>3</td><td>7</td><td>5</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kobe Bryant</td><td>1</td><td>8</td><td>7</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Magic Johnson</td><td>6</td><td>11</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Draymond Green</td><td>6</td><td>11</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Zach Randolph</td><td>6</td><td>11</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
<img src='http://exchangedownloads.smarttech.com/public/content/2c/2c4cb6ee-579f-4404-b573-c554ba6bf7f4/previews/medium/0001.png' class='myimg' id='court'>
```

CSS:

```
.mytable {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.mytable td {
  text-align: left;
  border: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.myimg {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#showimg").click(function(e) {
  $("#court").show();
});
```

Comment: The fiddle you posted is different from your code, it has an alert statement when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your table in element with relative position, than place the image (also in container with absolute position). That way you have better control over those elements. Check it out:

```js
$("#showimg").click(function(e) {
    $(".myimg").toggle();
});
```

```css
.mytable {
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.mytable td {
    text-align: left;
    border: solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.myimg {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.table_container {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='showimg'>
    Show/Hide Court
</button>
<div class="table_container">
    <table class='mytable'>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Jordan</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LeBron</td>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kobe</td>
            <td>Bryant</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magic</td>
            <td>Johnson</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="myimg">
        <img src='http://exchangedownloads.smarttech.com/public/content/2c/2c4cb6ee-579f-4404-b573-c554ba6bf7f4/previews/medium/0001.png' id='court' />
    </div>

</div>
```

Also at **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7g9dtxt/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/f7g9dtxt/3/

```js
$('.yourImage').toggle();
$("#showimg").click(function(e) {
 $('.yourImage').toggle();
});
```

```css
.mytable td {
  text-align: left;
  border: solid;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.mytable {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
.yourImage {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='showimg'>
Show Court
</button>
<table class='mytable'>
<tr><td>Michael</td><td>Jordan</td><td>5</td><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td>LeBron</td><td>James</td><td>3</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kobe</td><td>Bryant</td><td>1</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Magic</td><td>Johnson</td><td>6</td><td>11</td></tr>
</table>
<span class="yourImage">
  Put an img tag here!
</span>
```

Comment: Think he wanted centered table (Part of the problem is that I want the table itself to be centered)?